# list monthly active, churn, new users from user log table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to categorize the users as new (first login within past 30 days), churn (no login past 30 days), resurrected (first login was older than past past 60 days and last login was within past 30 days), active(user logged in 2 consecutive months including current)

```
user_log table

user_id | login_date
101 2021-01-11
101 1/11/21
101 1/12/21
101 12/16/20
101 12/31/20
102 1/11/21
102 12/25/20
103 1/11/21
103 12/20/20
103 12/23/20
103 11/13/20
103 11/14/20
108 1/12/21
108 1/13/21
108 12/12/20
108 11/13/20
113 1/12/21
113 11/13/20
115 1/11/21
115 12/17/20
116 1/12/21
116 11/14/20
118 12/14/20
118 11/14/20
123 1/14/21
123 11/14/20
```

something like this as a result set

```
user_id|active| churn|resurrected| new
101 1   0   0   0
102 1   0   0   0
103 1   0   0   0
108 1   0   0   0
113 0   0   1   0
115 1   0   0   0
116 0   0   1   0
118 0   1   0   0
123 0   0   1   0
```

Comment: Check max, min are in the appropriate intervals

Comment: @Serg max doesn't work if the user is active in current as well as in past month

Comment: Yes, you need to check both max, min to detect 'resurrected'.

Comment: @Serg max and min doesn't work to find active users(who logged in this month as well as previous month)

Comment: How much consecutive months will render a user as an 'active' ?

Comment: @Serg current + past would be active, I updated my question to reflect active users in the result set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228088/discussion-between-gabs-and-serg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, active `id` must have logins both in last 30 days and in previous 30 days.

```
select id
 , case when 
           CURRENT_DATE - max(login_date) <= 30 
       and CURRENT_DATE - max(case when CURRENT_DATE - login_date > 30  then login_date end) <= 60
   then 1 else 0 end active
 , case when CURRENT_DATE - max(login_date) > 30 then 1 else 0 end churn
 , case when 
           CURRENT_DATE - max(login_date) <= 30 
       and CURRENT_DATE - max(case when CURRENT_DATE - login_date > 30  then login_date end) > 60
   then 1 else 0 end resurrected
 , case when CURRENT_DATE - min(login_date) <= 30 then 1 else 0 end new_
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

> (first login within past 30 days), churn (no login past 30 days), resurrected (first login was older than past past 60 days and last login was within past 30 days), active(used logged in consecutive months)

You can use aggregation and conditional logic:

```
select user_id,
       (case when min(login_date) >= current_date - interval '30 day'
             then 'new'
             when max(login_date) < current_date - interval '30 day'
             then 'churn'
             when min(login_date) < current_date - interval '60 day' and
                  max(login_date) >= current_date - interval '30 day'
             then 'resurrected'
             when date_trunc('month', max(login_date)) = date_trunc(current_date) and
                  count(*) filter (where date_trunc('month', login_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month') > 0
             then 'active'
             else 'something else'
        end) as classification
from user_log ul
group by user_id
```

Comment: @ Gordon how can I find 'active' users who logged in current as well as previous month with first login date as beyond past 60 days ?

Comment: @gabs . . . I missed that.  In any case, perhaps it is "something else".  At the very least, you need to explain -- **in the question** -- what "active" really means.  The description is ambiguous.

Comment: my bad, I updated description and the result set to reflect the active users

Comment: Your question still does not define "consecutive months".